# Laravel + nullable foreign keys

Tags: laravel

I've got a form with a dropdown selection that lets you choose a foreign key for a particular model. The top option is always something like

```
<option value="">please select</option>
```

So when I fill my model with this data from the form,

```
$booking = new Booking($data);
```

And try to save it,

```
$booking->save();
```

It always fails because that violates the FK constraint because Laravel isn't smart enough to nullify this field for me. Thus I came up with this little hack:

```
public function save() {
    if(!$this->vehicle_id) $this->vehicle_id = null;
    if(!$this->driver_id) $this->driver_id = null;
    parent::save();
}
```

But is there no way to tell Laravel which fields represent FKs and should be set to null if they an integer > 0?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17452923/empty-string-instead-of-null-values-eloquent

Answer (score 16):

One possible solution is to use [set mutators](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) for all your foreign keys:

```
public function setVehicleIdAttribute($value) {
    $this->attributes['vehicle_id'] = $value ?: null;
}

public function setDriverIdAttribute($value) {
    $this->attributes['driver_id'] = $value ?: null;
}
```

Comment: Great answer on something that took me forever to figure out. One note that may help: Remember to name the mutator with the ID -- ie it is not mutating the relationship function, but rather the db field. I was making the mistake of calling the function 'setVehicleAttribute' after the function instead of 'setVehicleIdAttribute' per the example above. Laravel then missed catching the mutator. Obvious in hindsight.. but took forever to find.

Comment: YESSSS! I had my sales tax field set to nullable and in my select I had a "no tax" option where the value was set to null, but I would still get the foreign key constraint error whenever I tried to create a record. This was a great solution, thank you!