# Laravel: migration default() field does not work

Tags: php, html, laravel

i having troubles with my migration field default('No description'), i need to save a default value for my null fields on my form, but when i save, my form data stores empty fields.. why? i'm working with Laravel 5.2 and it is my code:

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('combos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('item_name');
        $table->string('description')->nullable()->default('No description');
        $table->decimal('price', 5, 2);
        $table->decimal('buy_price', 5, 2);   
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

My view:

```
    <div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('item_name','Item: ',['class'=>'control-label col-md-2']) !!}
    <div class="col-md-7" >
        {!! Form::text('item_name',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Enter a item name','required','min'=>5]) !!}<br/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('price','Price: ',['class'=>'control-label col-md-2']) !!}
    <div class="col-md-7" >
        {!! Form::text('buy_price',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Enter a price','required']) !!}<br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what does your controller look like?

Comment: It just doing this: Combo::create($request->all());

Comment: checkout this answer: [Empty string instead of null values Eloquent](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19101473/3049893)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your store function do this

```
$input = $request->all();
$input['description'] = $request->description;
Combos::create($input);
```

Comment: Thank for ur reply, i did something like that, but it's strange because my other projects works fine, I guess the problem is by the version, it seems 5.2.45 doesn't suport that =/ 
I doubt remains..