# Mysql Views - Auto incremental not working (through Eloquent ORM)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, view

For a project I have multiple databases set-up which should be working cross-site. I got one "master" website that contains all (important) tables such as users and categories and groups. Then I also have "slave" websites set-up, basically forming a website-cluster. All of these websites reside on the same database.

The slave websites have Views connected to the Tables from the master and getting the results through Eloquent works flawlessly, I get the results I should.

Now the problem is when I try to insert something into the slave (view) as the auto-increments doesn't seem to be working / accounted for.

I suppose a solution could be to run a `SELECT COUNT ..` query and increase the returning Integer by one, but that doesn't feel like a solution that should be used.

**Some information that should be useful:**

The view is created by the following query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW {$this->tablename} AS SELECT * FROM {$this->source}.{$this->tablename} WITH CASCADED CHECK OPTION
```

The commands I try to execute are as follows:

```
// Create a new id/entry in the Group table.
$__model = new \App\Group;
$__model->setConnection('ext_connection');
$__model->save();

// Create the translations here..
```

**Versions information:**

I am running MySQL version: **mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.17, for Linux (x86_64)**

I am using Laravel version: **5.4.21**

I am using php version: **PHP 7.1.4-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1**

I hope someone could enlighten me how I can insert properly into Views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after tinkering about in artisan tinker, I came to the realization that the Eloquent ORM does not insert empty fields as NULL values (as should be the case following the MySQL standards), but rather leaves them completely empty.

Inserting into Views this way throws an exception that it is missing column values, which is a correct error to be thrown out for a View.

So, a good way to solve this issue would be something like is described in the following thread: [View Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17452923/empty-string-instead-of-null-values-eloquent).